# Why is this function not correctly inserting a new node in a list?

Tags: c, list, function, pointers, struct

I'm trying to write a C header and source file to create a list ADT.
I've written the following prototypes in the header file (List.h):

```
#include "Item.h"

typedef struct lista *list;

/* ... */
list ListInit();
int HeadInsert(item i, list l);
int PrintList(list l);
/* ... */
```

Then, in the corresponding C source file (List.c), I declared the 'struct lista' type, as follows:

```
typedef struct listNODE *link;

struct listNODE {
    item element;
    link next;
};

struct lista {
    link head;
    link tail;
    int size;
};
```

And a few functions, inclusing the following ones:

```
list ListInit() {
    list l;

    l=malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    l->head=l->tail=NULL;
    l->size=0;

    return l;
}
```

---

```
int HeadInsert(item i, list l) {
    link x;

    x=malloc(sizeof(struct listNODE));

    if(x==NULL) return (-1);

    if(l->head == NULL) {
        l->head = l->tail = x;
        l->head->next = NULL;
    } else {
        x->next=l->head;
        l->head=x;
    }

    l->head->element=i;
    l->size++;

    return 1;
}
```

---

```
int PrintList(list l) {
    link t;

    if(l->head==NULL) {
        return (-1);
    }

    for(t=l->head;t!=NULL;t=t->next) {
        printi(t->element);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Where 'printi' has been defined in Item.h/Item.c as follows:

```
void printi(item x) {
printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n%.2f\n",x.name,x.surname,x.matr,x.career.credits,x.career.mid);
}
```

I'm not getting any compilation error, nor any CppCheck static analysis warning. Conceptually it seem to me that these functions should work, but I'm surely wrong and I haven't correcly written them (I should really do more exercises on this, since I'm findind it a bit difficult to always understand, mainly when there are many pointers involved) since they do not work as they should.
Why aren't these function working? If I declare, in the client module (main.c or client.c), a new list (let's call it listname) and, after initializing it by

```
listname=ListInit();
```

and then crete a new node on it (passing a new item, previusly read using the 'scani' function defined in Item.c/Item.h), the PrintList(listname); function seems to fail (it sometimes, but not always, prints random things instead of the correct fields of 'item', just like the pointers were not correctly assigned).
Do you know why?

The 'scani' function is defined as follows:

```
void scani(item *x) {
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%35s",buffer);
    x->name=strdup(buffer);
    printf("Surname: ");
    scanf("%35s",buffer);
    x->surname=strdup(buffer);
    printf("Code: ");
    scanf("%35s",buffer);
    x->matr=strdup(buffer);
    printf("Exams passed: ");
    scanf("%d",&x->career.credits);
    printf("Average mark: ");
    scanf("%f",&x->career.mid);
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What happens and what you expect to happen? A bit confused. By the way it looks like there's no use for `tail` variable.

Comment: I insert a new item in the client (and the pass it to the function).
Name: test
Surname: test_surname
Code: 555555
Exams passed: 45
Average mark: 23.12

When I try to print the elements (items) in the list i get (I'm now using a version of printi which also prints what each field is):
Name: -&-
-urname: test_surname
Code: 555555
Exams passed: 45
Average mark: 23.12

And I don't really know what's happening! :(

The tail variabile is used in some other functions declared in List.h, but it is of almost no use here. It only should memorize the address of the last node in the list.

Comment: And what happens when you try to?

Comment: It seems like the pointers are somewhat wrong (I've updated the previous comment. Sorry, I accidentally confirmed it before I was able to finish writing it!)...

Comment: I probably found it! In the client I was freeing the memory of x.name, x.surname, x.matr in a temporary item (the item read using 'scani()') thinking that I would have never used them again. I do not use the item again but I use the memory these pointers pointed to (I should have not freed it!)! If I free that memory, I'm then trying to access unallocated memory, with the unexpected result! So the problem was apparently in my client.c file!
Thank you very much anyway!!

Comment: You might accept and upvote my answer too. :)

Comment: The comment, you mean? :)